# Dynamic hierarchical pages and SEO

Tags: php, sql, mod-rewrite, laravel

Cheers everyone!

Please bear with me, I really did do some research on this, but I couldn't come to a final solution, hence I'm here to hear your opinions.

What I want to build is a small i18n-CMS with dynamic hierarchical pages such as:

```
domain.tld/en/I/am/a/path
```

I want to find the least performance intense way that allows me to have beautiful, SEO and human-friendly URLs.

I use a Closure-Table, so two tables in the database, one for the pagenodes and one for the pathtree plus another table for the localised page, that references a certain pagenode (three in total).

My different solutions so far:

1. Sure I could make an algorithm, that goes through all the different request segments and checks if there is an English "path" under an "a" under an "am" under an "I", but this seems very unwise considering a multitude of page-hits.

Or is it?

Positive: I wouldn't need to save the path anywhere, because it would be calculated. So moving pages around wouldn't need to recalculate the path and save it again.

1. I could simply save the whole path to the database, as VARCHAR(2000) or something and then just check if there is a page with path "I/am/a/path" in English language and get that one.

This seems to be rather messy.

1. As I do it now. Currently I add an "ID" at the end of my path. Such as:

   domain.tld/en/I/am/a/path.1

So if you enter "domain.tld/en.1" you get forwarded to the one with the right slug. But here again I need to save the slug to the database, for each single page.

Also I would love to get rid of the id (could I do this with mod-rewrite and .htaccess?)

Any more insights on this one? As I'm not a webdeveloper, so I'm not really sure regarding performance.

Kindest regards,

Meren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that page request will happen a million times more often than an editor changing a page address. So I would definitely go with the save-to-db option. What you can do is create an extra field in which you save the 'slug' for that page, in combination with .htaccess you can redirect pages from the 'slug' addresses. For example in  http://www.fuuu.com/futest-fu , 'futest-fu' is a slug which could be rewritten to an ID number (or anything you would want it to be). Amongst others, Wordpress works this way. Check out this discussion for some insights: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/where-are-the-permalinks-slug-stored-in-the-database

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right, when you say that a page is more often called, than changed. Anyways, they use a combination of both, they calculate it AND save the slug (but only the slug) the problem here is, what if I have a page like: "domain.tld/en/one/two/contact" and also "domain.tld/en/three/four/contact" the slug would be "contact" in both cases, so I would need another query still. As I understand wordpress has a table where they store the slug and the id? So I'd first look into this table, see if there is a slug (or rather path in my case) and then call the page with the id. Nice one.

Comment: Yes, so Wordpress basically saves the ID + the slug in one row (so with one of them you can get the other). If you have different url's for a contact page, I assume that you want these to be 2 different pages, right? So the Wordpress method suffices.

Comment: This would be true, yes. But I don't see the benefit of a distinct table right now. Why save the slug/path and id to another table, if I could save the slug/path directly to the page? I would save another query if the slug was in the page-table.

Comment: Well you would save the ID/slug with all the other page information (so in the same table). I'm not sure how you want to save info to the page itself?

Comment: Simply add another column like "path" and save the path to the page there. I don't see why wordpress uses another "terms_relationships"-table, which they need to query. If I save it to the page I can say: "Page::where('language', $language)->where('path', $path)->first();"

Comment: O, well they save it to the same table! They save the slug in the post_name column of the wp_posts table, which is the same which holds all the other page/post info like ID, content, etcetera.

Comment: One more question though... isn't a query for a VARCHAR slower than for an int? So why not query for the id and then remove it via .htaccess?

Comment: I'm sorry, english isn't my mothertongue. So once again (just to clarify this.) In my queries I go for the slug/path?! Like: Page::where('path', $path)->first(); I just thought that querying the path itself (VARCHAR) is much slower and more intense than querying the id. hence I started with domain.tld/en/path.id

Comment: If you want 'pretty' url's without vague ID numbers, then yes.

Comment: But everyone, even here in stackoverflow, says that querying a varchar is vastly(!) slower than querying an integer. If I have a long path it would get very slow I guess...

Comment: You said yourself: Also I would love to get rid of the id (could I do this with mod-rewrite and .htaccess?)

If you want to use an ID number, thats fine!

Comment: Yes, sure. I'm just a bit stunned that every major cms out there would really go for "query by varchar". I mean it looks much cleaner, but I really thought that you could add the id somehow "hidden" and just never show it...

Comment: Nope, you can't control the browser from a website and displaying the url in the address field is a browsers' job...

Comment: Okay, then query by slug/varchar it is. Thanks.